How to Convert an Encrypted RSA Private Key to Unencrypted [BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY] Format?
I recently encountered an issue while trying to convert an encrypted RSA private key to an unencrypted RSA key using OpenSSL 3.3.0 on my Mac. By default, the command outputs the key in "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" format, but I need it in "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" format.
Here's the command I initially used:
openssl rsa -in domain.key -out domain-rsa.key

Problem:
The output I got was:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----


I found that with version 3.0 and later of OpenSSL, the -traditional flag is required to get the desired format because OpenSSL has adopted PKCS#8 as the default standard. The correct command is:
openssl rsa -in domain.key -out domain-rsa.key -traditional

This command outputs the domain-rsa.key in the format I needed:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


What version specifically? This answer has to last the test of time, “newer version”, is specific enough. I have seen 5 year old versions be referred to as “newer”

Edit your answer. Comments are temporary
